# In R, how do I test $H_0: \beta_1+\beta_2=0$

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I am estimating the following model using the `lm` package in `R`:

$y_t = \alpha + \beta_1x_t + \beta_2 z_t$.

I am interest in the null hypothesis $H_0: \beta_1 + \beta_2=0$.

How can I test this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $\beta_1 + \beta_2 = 0$, then $\beta_1 = -\beta_2$, so $\beta_1 x_t + \beta_2 z_t = \beta_1 x_t - \beta_1 z_t = \beta_1 (x_t - z_t)$. So, in R, you can run

```
f1 <- lm(y ~ I(x - z), data = data)
f2 <- lm(y ~ x + z, data = data)
anova(f1, f2)
```

which will give you a test if the model where $\beta_1 + \beta_2 = 0$ (i.e., `f1`) fits worse than a model whether $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ can freely vary (i.e., `f2`). If the comparison is significant, then `f2` is the better model and you can reject the null hypothesis that $\beta_1 + \beta_2 = 0$.

More generally, you can use the `multcomp` package to test general linear hypotheses:

```
multcomp::glht(f2, linfct = "x + z = 0")
```

Comment: +1 for the `multcomp` recommendation, a great package!

Comment: Thank you so much, Noah! Especially for the multcomp package, really helped me out.

Answer (score 6):

Great thread which generated some great answers - though I have a feeling it will be moved to Stack Exchange because it is software related (the software being R).

To supplement Noah's answer, I will show an alternative way one can test the hypotheses of interest using the **multcomp** package.  [Note that we can't test just a null hypothesis - we need to specify an alternative hypothesis as well.]

Recall that the linear regression  model is:

$y_t = \alpha + \beta_1x_t + \beta_2 z_t$,

while the two competing hypotheses being tested are:

$H_0: \beta_1 + \beta_2 = 0$ and

$H_a: \beta_1 + \beta_2  \neq 0$.

Here, $H_0$ refers to the null hypothesis and $H_a$ refers to the alternative hypothesis.

**Step 1:**

The first thing we have to note is that the left hand side of the two stated hypotheses is nothing but a linear combination of the regression coefficients  $\alpha$, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$in the linear regression model.  Specifically:

$\beta_1 + \beta_2 = 0*\alpha + 1*\beta_1 + 1*\beta_2$,

where the weights given to the regression coefficients $\alpha$, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ in this linear combination are 0, 1 and 1, respectively.

**Step 2:**

We will define a matrix of weights W with a single row, which lists the weights of the regression coefficients:

W <- rbind(c(0, 1, 1))

This is what W looks like currently:

```
> W
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    1
```

**Step 3:**

We assign proper names to the row and column of weights W.  The row name will be *beta1 + beta2*.  The column names will be *alpha*, *beta1* and *beta2*.  This is just so that we can keep track of what linear combination of the coefficients $\alpha$, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ we are interested in testing.

```
rownames(W) <- c("beta1 + beta2")
colnames(W) <- c("alpha","beta1", "beta2")
W
```

This is what the beautified version of W looks like:

```
>     W
               alpha  beta1  beta2
beta1 + beta2      0      1      1
```

**Step 4:**

We fit the model and perform the test of the null hypothesis against the alternative hypothesis:

```
library(multcomp)

model <- lm(y ~ x + z, data = data) 

model.test <- glht(model, linfct = W)

summary(model.test)
```

If we generate the data with the commands below:

```
set.seed(1)

x = rnorm(100)
z = rnorm(100)
X = model.matrix(~x+z)
y = X%*%c(1,-2,3) + rnorm(100)

data <- data.frame(y=y, x=x)
```

here is what the R output would look like:

```
>     summary(model.test) 

         Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Fit: lm(formula = y ~ x + z, data = data)

Linear Hypotheses:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
beta1 + beta2 == 0   0.9676     0.1601   6.043 2.81e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

From this output, we can see that the p-value for the t-test used to test the null hypothesis against the alternative hypothesis is 2.81e-08 (which is scientific notation for 0.0000000281).

**Step 5:**

To estimate the value of $\beta1 + \beta2$ and compute an associated confidence interval, we can use the command:

```
confint(model.test)
```

whose output will look like this:

```
> confint(model.test)

         Simultaneous Confidence Intervals

Fit: lm(formula = y ~ x + z, data = data)

Quantile = 1.9847
95% family-wise confidence level


Linear Hypotheses:
                     Estimate  lwr     upr   
beta1 + beta2 == 0   0.9676    0.6498  1.2855
```

From this output, we can see that the estimated value of $\beta1 + \beta2$ is 0.9676 and the corresponding 95% confidence interval is (0.6498, 1.2855).

We can plot the confidence interval we computed via these commands:

```
par(mar=c(4,8,4,4))
plot(model.test)
```

[image]

Comment: You can get the $\neq$ sign in LaTeX using ```\neq```.

Comment: @Ben: Thank you! I edited my answer to include \neq, which I didn’t know about.  (It’s been centuries since I used Latex.)

Comment: You always have `\not` which will add a negating slash over the following symbol: `\not =` $\not =$, `\not <` $\not <$, `\not \approx` $\not\approx$, `\not\mapsto` $\not\mapsto$

Answer (score 3):

The variance of $\beta_1 + \beta_2$ is $\operatorname{Var}(\beta_1) + \operatorname{Var}(\beta_2)
 + 2\operatorname{Cov}(\beta_1,\beta_2)$. Obtain the variance and covaraince from the covariance matrix and construct an appropriate confidence interval.

Here is some R code.  I'm sure there is a package to do this, but until someone posts that, this should do fine.

```
x = rnorm(100)
z = rnorm(100)
X = model.matrix(~x+z)
y = X%*%c(1,-2,3) + rnorm(100)

model = lm(y~x+z)

sigma = vcov(model)

var_est = as.numeric(c(0,1,1)%*%sigma%*%c(0,1,1))
betas = coef(model)

(betas[2]+betas[3]) + c(-1,1)*1.96*sqrt(var_est)
```

Comment: You forgot to take the square root of the estimated variance.

Comment: Whoops! I’ll add that as soon as I get home

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try a Chi-square goodness of fit ( observed -expected) for your data points, for two models, one with $\beta_1= -\beta_2$ and another one where you use $\beta_2 \in (\beta_1 - \epsilon, \beta_1 + \epsilon )$  with your choice of $\epsilon >0 $ a Real number, and check the two Chi-squared statistics using the needed degrees of freedom.

Comment: @Noah: I mean regress the _data points_ used to derive $\beta_1, \beta_2$ . But let me double-check see if I am making sense.

Comment: I changed the answer.

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote?

Comment: You probably did not even understand my answer , yet downvoted.